# How to reference the CSS path properly?

Tags: java, maven, jsp, intellij-idea, classpath

I work with a Java/Spring project and the project structure is provided below,

[image]

I need to reference the `app.css` in the `index.jsp` file. Currently, I reference the following way in the `index.jsp` and the app doesn't get the `CSS` information's.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bitcoin Wallet</title>
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

In the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`, I provided the resources path as below,

[image]

The page I get in the localhost clearly doesn't have the css. How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use resources in spring mvc project you have to declare `mvc:resources`, to map url to a physical file path location.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/css/"
```

When you use `/resources/` in jsp file spring will map this url to `/resources/css/`.

Next you can reference css file in jsp file:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/app.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

And move `resources` folder into `webapp` folder as